# Using monad transformers in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, monads, monad-transformers

I'm getting myself familiar with monad transformers in OCaml using [monads](https://binaryanalysisplatform.github.io/bap/api/master/monads/Monads/Std/index.html) library.

Here is an example I'm working with:

```ml
open Base
open Stdio
open Monads.Std

module St = struct
  include Monad.State.T1 (Monoid.Int) (Monad.Ident)
  include Monad.State.Make (Monoid.Int) (Monad.Ident)
end

module W = Monad.Writer.Make (Monoid.String) (St)

let w_example =
  let open W in
  let writer =
    let* () = write "A" in
    let* () = lift (St.put 42) in
    return (-1)
  in
  let w_result = run writer in
  let s_result, state = St.run w_result 0 in
  s_result, state

let () = printf "((%d, %s), %d)\n" (fst (fst w_example)) (snd (fst w_example)) (snd w_example)
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there an automatic way to retrieve the result `-1`, the log `A`, and the state `42` all at once without manually `run`-ing all the composed monads inwards?
2. To `put` a new state into `W` monad, I needed to separate `St` module in order to expose `St.put`. `W` does not have `put` exposed. Is there a way if I just went with

```ml
module W =
  Monad.Writer.Make
    (Monoid.String)
    (struct
      include Monad.State.T1 (Monoid.Int) (Monad.Ident)
      include Monad.State.Make (Monoid.Int) (Monad.Ident)
    end)
```

without a separate `St`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can define a `run` function that goes through all the layer of the monad stack:

```
let run x st = St.run (W.run x) st
```

It is also a good place to define a more human-friendly return type like

```
type 'a t = { int_st : int;  string_st : string; return : 'a }
let run x st =
  let ((return, string_st), int_st) = St.run (W.run x) st in
  { int_st; string_st; return }
```

2. You need to construct `Monad.State.Make (Monoid.Int) (Monad.Ident)` before using its `put` function anyway. Trying to avoid naming the `St` monad would be mostly unpractical.